# Story about Dragons and Gryphons featuring a funeral

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

Hoping someone can help me figure out this book I read a child I haven't been able to recall the name of.

I would have read this paper back in the mid-late 2000s but easily could have been a bit older than that. I'm pretty sure the spine of the book was red, with a cover featuring a few dragons huddled together.

A review on the back of book I remember comparing it to the *Redwall* books.

The story is about some dragon society that lives in the woods. The main plot I do not recall Many details of. Near the middle of the story the leader dragon, who I'm pretty sure was named Firestorm, dies and there's a funeral scene of the other dragons gathering around a pyre.

There is also chapters about a few gryphons who I think live in the swamp, I recall their parts dealing with tensions between two brothers who I think where heirs to the throne and involves on of them killing the other.

That's all the details I recall now, any help with this burning question would br great.